# Javascript / jQuery - anyway to shorthand this or make less obtuse

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have this constructor set up with some prototypes methods and because I need the behavior (that this object creates ) to apply to a few diff. elements, I was wondering if there is a better way than doing the following.

```
var MAINFUNC = function(opts){
 this.options = {
      item1  : 'somevalue'
  },
  this.init(opts);
}

MAINFUNC.prototype = {
   someFunc1: function(){
       // do stuff
    },
   someFunc2: function(){
       // do stuff
    },
   someFunc3: function(){
         // do stuff
   },
init: function(data){
      $.extend(this.options, data);
      this.someFunc1();
     }
 };
var obj1Create =  new MAINFUNC({ someoptions });
var obj2Create = new MAINFUNC({ someoptions });
var obj2Create = new MAINFUNC({ someoptions });
```

So, its the last three obj instantiations that seem a tad bit obtuse. Perhaps I am incorrect, but I am thinking there is a more refined way of doing this. And yes, each of thos obj*Create does represent a diff element which needs the behavior that is supplied by MAINFUNC.

Thank you.

Comment: if by the term `elements` you mean `DOM elements` put your code into a jQuery plugin so you can write `$(selector).myFuncPlugin(options)`. `each` loop within plugin will create multiple instances

Comment: I was gonna go that route, but this functionality doesn't quite fit the bill of a plugin. The usage would be minimal and not sure chaining would be useful for what I am doing. I understand your point though. I might end up going that route if Plynx's answer below isn't working for me. Thanks Charlie.

Comment: it's not just about chaining, if plugin affects DOM elements,you have the element(s) exposed within plugin is more the point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var MAINFUNC = function(opts)
{
   var m = Object.create(MAINFUNC.prototype);
   m.options = { ... };
   m.init(opts);
   return m;
};

var o = [{someoptions}, {someoptions}, {someoptions}].map(MAINFUNC);
// objects are all now in array
```

A side benefit of this approach is it makes `MAINFUNC` work whether you use `new` or not. This makes it much more manageable, especially with collection functions.

Comment: I'll give this a try. Thanks. I'll accept once I have tested. Appreciate your prompt response.

Comment: Plynx - I have a question for you. Does your way (or the way I created) gain me anything over using the jQuery plugin way? Caveat - this MAINFUNC will have limited use across the site.

Comment: @jamesemanon The JQuery plugin way allows you to use arbitrary selectors and chain them into your function. but you can do the same thing with `$('your selector').each(function(i,v) { ... });` without making a plugin. Where `...` goes you just do something with each element in the selection, for example interacting with `MAINFUNC` (from your example I can't tell exactly how they are supposed to interact so I can't say what goes in there.)